# И снова Русский медвежонок

Tags: словообразование, стилистика

В "Русском медвежонке" за 2010 год есть вопрос:
"В русской литературе XIX–XX вв. можно встретить слово...
(А) áстолько; (Б) и´столько; (В) óстолько;
(Г) ýстолько; (Д) э´столько". Мы с внуком пытались найти ответ на него, но безуспешно. Может, кто-нибудь из коллег поможет?

Comment: А для какого класса был вопрос?

Comment: Да для какого ни возьми - все равно глухарь. Слово даже не из пассивного словарного запаса современного человека. Что-то из лексикона Бояна. Без Интернета можно угадать только случайно.

Comment: Вопрос был для 10-11 класса. Меня тоже он смутил невозможностью ответить без разыскивания в словарях

Comment: ВО невнимательная! Да у меня бабушка так говорила. Но не как в вопросе, а как у Даля. "Вот сЭстолько возьми"

Comment: Если нужен точный ответ с примерами - я бы тоже не ответила. Но чисто интуитивно, по звучанию, склонялась к последнему варианту. Он как-то ложится на ухо. Видимо, сидит в подсознании, где-то читан или слышан.

Comment: Покая эти ответы искал нашел немало "интуитивных" ответов во всяких там "ответы.mail.ru" и подобных. Мало кто принимал в расчет правильный вариант. Собственно русских слов (за исключением междометий и местоимений), начинающихся на Э не существует.

Comment: Вот-вот... Потому вместе с предлогом  "с" и узнала слово.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ЭСТОЛЬ, эстолько нареч. столько, состолько (настолько), вот сколько, толико, так. Эстоль маловато, а вот с эстолько хватит. Эстоль они (пироги) высоконьки, эстоль они широко́ньки, эстоль они мяко́шеньки, песня. Хоть бы эстоличко дал!

(Даль)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ и за оперативность. Буду благодарен, если подскажете источник.

Comment: Это словарь Даля, я написал. Вам ссылка нужна? Сейчас посмотрю.

Не открывает на словарях почему-то. Ну вот он на яндексе [есть][1]:

Пока искал вот еще нашел:

Э'СТОЛЬ и Э'СТОЛЬКО, нареч. (простореч.). Вот сколько. Эх, ежели бы мне тоже почитать с эстоль! М. Горький. 
([Ушаков][2])

[1]: http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F/%D0%AD%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%AC/

[2]: http://feb-web.ru/feb/ushakov/ush-abc/30/us4e3412.htm

Comment: Еще раз спасибо. Такая искренняя готовность помочь всегда трогает.

Comment: Не не за что. 
Я не воспринимаю это как помощь. Только как решение некоей задачки, к чему у меня действительно слабость. Тем более - олимпиадной.